# Add properties name label or id to a feature

Tags: openlayers

I'm new to OpenLayers 3 and I'm trying to add a property (id, name or label) to a feature to get it back on click later, to identify that particular feature.

Is it possible?

I haven't found any answer doing this yet. Something like:

```
var point_feature1 = new ol.Feature({ }); 
point_feature1.setProperties('description', "description 1");
point_feature1.setId(666);
...
```

And then onclick:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {             
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature, layer) {
      console.log("feature",feature.getId());
      return [feature, layer];   
    });                                                           
});
```

Answer (score 20):

You have an error in how you use the `setProperties` method. It is intended to set multiple properties at once and takes an object as input, which contains a list of key-value pairs:

```
point_feature1.setProperties({'name':'abcd', 'description':'xyz'})
```

The `set` method is used set one property at a time:

```
point_feature1.set('name', 'abcd')
```

With either method, you can then retrieve the name/description with the get method:

```
point_feature1.get('name');
```

The way you're using `setId` and `getId` looks fine.